# How to Play MP3 Files in C code using FMOD?

Tags: c, file, include, mp3, audio-player

I'm trying to play a simple file in my c code and so I looked up how to do it on Stack Overflow, but when I tried to apply the answer, which was to download FMOD and use it, I got an error.

The code was:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <inc/fmod.h>
    
    FSOUND_SAMPLE* handle;
    int main()
    {
     // init FMOD sound system
       FSOUND_Init (44100, 32, 0);
    
       // load and play mp3
       handle=FSOUND_Sample_Load (0,"mp3.file",0, 0, 0);
       FSOUND_PlaySound (0,handle);
    
       // wait until the users hits a key to end the app
       while (!_kbhit())
       {
       }
    
       // clean up
       FSOUND_Sample_Free (handle);
       FSOUND_Close();
    }
```

but the error told me that:

```
 "gcc -Wall -c "Cases.c" (in directory: C:\Users\xeobi\Documents\C Files)
Cases.c:5:10: fatal error: inc/fmod.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <inc/fmod.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Compilation failed."
```

Comment: It's telling you that you are trying to include something that doesn't exist. Do you have the library downloaded and in the correct place?

Comment: I have the FMOD Engine downloaded, but where should I place it for C to read the library?